# matrix profile vs. singular spectrum transformation

Tags: time-series, anomaly-detection, change-point

Does anyone have experience with singular spectrum transformation and in particular also a comparison with the matrix profile?

I would want to better understand the practical differences.

So far, I have observed that SST only supports a single dimension, whereas matrix profile recently started to partially support multivariate time-series.